# Expo firebase: verifyBeforeUpdateEmail does not send email

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, email-verification

I am trying to verify an email before being updated, with this code:

```
try {
    await verifyBeforeUpdateEmail(auth.currentUser, "aaa@bbb.ccc")
    //...code1
} catch (e) {
    //...code2
}
```

Even if code1 is called - as the function worked correctly - the verification email does not arrive.

Also, I do not know which email template is used by this function. I have four templates on firebase console:

- Verify email address
- Password reset
- Email address edited
- Sign up notification